# Power Bi - two column dates

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, data-modeling, powerbi-desktop

I would like an help for power bi. I have several projects in rows and 12 months in different columns for budget, plus other 12 months for actual expenses.

I have done unpivot to have the actual expenses and budget in two different columns (instead of 24 --> 2 times 12 months). The problem is that I end up with two different columns with the date, one for the actual sales and one for budget and I am stucked. How to solve this issue? Any better way to do?

Thanks

**Original Data**
[image]

**Desired Output**
[image]

.........................................................................

UPDATE: latest issue with sorting (index after pivot function)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81xcT.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to add detail ... what does your data currently look like ... what do you want it to look like.  Add an image or table with the sample data

Comment: ![original data example (with only 3 months to simplify)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPD3R.png)

![desired data example (one date column and three desired values columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwWuF.png)

![what I really have in my set of data as final result (three different date columns with three different values columns)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwx8l.png)

Answer (score 0):

With adequate data, it is now easier to see what you are dealing with and what you want.

- It appears as if you need to repeat the Project and Manager columns.  So select them and then Unpivot other columns
- Then split the Attribute Column into Month and what I called a "ValueType" column (Budget, Actual, Latest)
- Pivot with no aggregation on the ValueType column
- Then some cleanup with sorting and re-arranging the columns.

*Explore the Applied steps and also read the comments in the M-Code to better understand the algorithm*
***Edit:** Original code edited to make columns more dynamic, and also allow for possibility of more "Types" of values (eg: Budget, Actual, Last, something else)*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],

//Get list of monthcolumns for setting data type and Count
    //if columns will only be Project, Manager, and then various Date columns, you can use the simpler function
    //if not, you'll need a different Selection function
   monthCols = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each
        not (_ = "Project" or _="Manager")),
    typer = {{"Project", Int64.Type},{"Manager", Text.Type}} & 
                      List.Transform(monthCols, each {_, Int64.Type}),

    //How many value types and months
    v = List.Transform(monthCols,each Text.Split(_," "){0}),
    months = List.Distinct(v,Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
    numMonths = List.Count(months),

    vt=List.Transform(monthCols,each Text.Split(_," "){1}),
    valueTypes= List.Distinct(vt,Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
  
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,typer),

//Unpivot all except Project and Manager columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Project", "Manager"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Split the Attribute (budget date/type) column to separate the Month and the Type
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Month", "ValueType"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Month", type text}, {"ValueType", type text}}),
    trimAndProper= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{
        {"Month", each Text.Trim(Text.Proper(_))},
        {"ValueType", each Text.Trim(Text.Proper(_))}}),

//Add Index of Month Number for sorting later on
 monthNumber = Table.AddColumn(trimAndProper, "monthNumber", 
    each Date.Month(Date.FromText([Month] & " 2021"))),

//Pivot on ValueType
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(monthNumber, List.Distinct(monthNumber[ValueType]), "ValueType", "Value"),

//Add another Index - Integer/Division for sorting
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Index.1", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "Integer-Division", 
        each Number.IntegerDivide([Index.1], numMonths), Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division",{"Index.1"}),

//Sort, reorder and rename
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Integer-Division", Order.Ascending}, {"monthNumber", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"monthNumber", "Integer-Division"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"Project", "Month"} & valueTypes & {"Manager"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

**Original Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ron 
I have tried your approach (first without sorting), but I end up with twice some months such as September and other ones:

Problem months (see the picture in my other answer, since here can't attach it)

I have then tried to do some steps following your extra steps for sorting and it seems ok until the pivot, then the month associate with number of the index seems not anymore ok. I found the approach a bit complicated at the start, thus I inserted manually everywhere needed instead of numMonths directly the value 12.

Hope you can help me to solve this issues, Thanks

Comment: @A_powerBi It appears from the graph output that your sample data is not truly representative of your actual data or desired table (before the graph) output, so I am not surprised that you are having problems. I can't do much without representative data and representative table output.

Comment: @A_powerBi Some questions based on your graph: Does your original data include the Year in the column headers?  If so, what, exactly, does it look like? And do you want the results grouped by month/year or all months aggregated together?  The solution I posed assumed your data looked like you presented it, with only the month name in the original column headers. Lots of difference between the two.

Comment: Hi @Ron thank you for your support. I have solved the first issue cleaning the format of the months, so now if I plot them I see only the ones should be there, not repeated. In terms of data the only difference between my dataset and the one shared as example is that in my real one I have 12 months ranging from June-2021 until May-2022. The only problem left now is with sorting, it seems to me that the index was working well before the pivot, but then after the pivot lose of corrispondency with the month ( I attach the picture in my main post). Thank you again!

Comment: Ron answering to your last question, my data are in the following format month-year, starting from June-2021 until May-2022. It is fine to have them singularly in the column month as we did for the example data. I just would like to have them in progressive order from June-2021 until May-2022. Thanks

Comment: @A_powerBi More important would be an example of your original, representative data. Do we just change the month in the original to month-year, with no spaces?

Comment: yes no spaces... I don't think it is a problem since there are no spaces, otherwise I could have also removed the year. You can see them in the picture I uploaded above at the end of my initial post in the update section. Thanks

Comment: @A_powerBi OK. If sorting the dates in chronological order for each Project is the only problem, then just change the `monthNumber` line to `monthNumber = Table.AddColumn(trimAndProper, "monthNumber", each let split=Text.Split([Month],"-") in Date.FromText("1/" & split{0} & "/20" & split{1}))` so it creates a full date instead of just the month number, and takes the year into account.

Comment: @A_powerBi Also, if you want your Column Chart to show the dates in alphabetical order, then delete the "Month" column and use the "monthNumber" column for the Axis.

Comment: Thanks @Ron. I will be trying soon this change, but it seems to me clear the way you tackle the problem. Anyhow is there a way to set as format  of the date in power query only the month/year, instead of a day/month/year? This is just for visualization purpose in the charts, since each value corresponds not to a specific date, but to the whole value in the month.  Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: @A_powerBi As I implied, if you want your columns properly sorted in the chart, you should leave them as "real dates" in your table.  For visualization purposes in the chart, format the date there (`Axis item (monthNumber unless you renamed it) =>down arrow=>field settings=>number format`)